# Elasticsearch alerting based notifications

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-percolate

I write an e-commerce website. I use elasticsearch.

I must write a price alert system with product prices.

I know Percolate query can be used for this job. But I did research on the internet, but I could not find a page with examples.

How can I? Is there a know website this subject?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.gembalabs.com/2015/04/15/elasticsearch-tutorial-what-is-percolation/

Comment: I tried this , but this used version is 2. My ES Version 5 :/

Answer (score 1):

You can see their default documentation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html

**Procedure is given below:**

1. Create one percolator index with required mappings.
2. Put user rules (booleans) in that index.
3. Make search request in percolator index for each and every new product which is stored into your database.
4. If matches found then send email/sms to the customer or store alert details into a db table.